# Usage of whenever is so

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Can I write it like this :

> The output is black whenever the input is so.

Or is it enough to say

> The output is black whenever the input is.

Comment: It is much clearer to say _The output is black whenever the input is also black_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no common English construction **whenever is so*;
*so* is not used that way in Modern English.

*So*, alone, at the end of a clause, meaning "*like **that***",
can only be used in speech phatically, with a gesture or some other way of directing
the attention of the addressee to whatever ***that*** is sposta be.  So if you **said** the first sentence
to somebody, they should be looking for the color of the current input.

It can't be used referentially at all, which excludes all writing, since writing is only referential.
I.e, if you **wrote** this to somebody, they wouldn't be able to see the color of the current input.

- *The output is black whenever the input is (also) black*

As mplungjan has pointed out, simply repeating the word that was replaced by *so* is

1. much clearer; in fact, unambiguous
2. exactly the same length; no syllables were lost during this syntactic operation
3. easier; no syntactic pro-forms need be inserted, no deletions, no structural meltdowns
4. more elegant; the term that is to be matched is right there emphasizing itself iconically.

> This all, of course, assumes that this ***is*** what you want to mean by saying
>
> - **The output is black whenever the input is so.*
>
> It's not entirely clear.

Comment: "The former is nonsingular whenever the latter is so": http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.3641.pdf (2011). "we should findthe former organ affected whenever the latter is so": http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dRxAAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA722&lpg=PA722&dq=%22whenever+the+latter+is+so%22&source=bl&ots=XCOFJVxI0j&sig=sL_lrdLC72Fq0f-viXIe2MMXjpk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7p3VUsLTGM6UhQfMxoHQAw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22whenever%20the%20latter%20is%20so%22&f=false (1826). There are others.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. But it's not really part of Modern English, like many other dead constructions. Maybe it'll show up as an NPI eventually.